# Click on <li> tag from a bootstrap select2 dropdown in internjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, intern

I am writing some function test on a form and I am running into issues selecting values from a bootstrap-select2 drop-down.

If you are unfamiliar with Select2, here are some examples;
https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/3.5.1.html

All the drop-downs are un-order list that appear when you click on the drop-down.

I click on the drop-down with;
`.findById('select2-chosen-1').click().end()`

The above lines makes the un-ordered list appear, but I am unsure how to select a specific selection.

if I do the following I can print out all the selections;

```
.findById('select2-results-1')
      .getVisibleText()
      .then(function(text) {
        console.info(text);
 })
```

I tried to get all the li tag names under that , `.findAllByTagName('li')`, but I am not sure what to do with that array.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be very helpful. Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open the dropdown, you just need to find the particular item you want to select and click it. I generally use `findByXpath`, or a combination of `findByCssSelector` and `findByXpath`, when I'm trying to find something that contains text, like:

```
.findById('select2-chosen-1')
.click()
.end()

.findByCssSelector('.select2-drop-active .select2-results')
.findByXpath('.//li[div[text()="Alaska"]]')
.click()
.end(2)
```

The code above finds the Select2 and clicks it, then finds the dropdown result node. With the result node as the current reference, it uses an XPath expression to find the `li` that contains a `div` with text "Alaska", then clicks the `li`. The `end(2)` after the click handles both the `findByXpath` and `findByCssSelector` calls.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just a heads up for anyone looking at this, Leadfoot uses `findByXpath`, that is with a lowercase `p`.